# Unable to load the requested file: home.php

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, activerecord

In the codeigniter I get this message :

> ```
> Unable to load the requested file: home.php
> ```

controller :

```
cp/
    Login
```

[image]

---

views :

```
cp/
    home.blade.php
```

address :

http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/cp/login

`routes` :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['pages/(:any)']       = "page/get/$1";

$controllers = array('bank','baseController','contact','cron','faq','inbox','index','livescore',
'msg','news','odds','page','profile','poll','rss','setting','traction','user' ,'shop' , 'product' , 'ad'  ,
    'comment','home','login');

foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    $route[$controller] = $controller."/index";
    $route[$controller."/(:any)"] = $controller."/$1";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your folder structure, Your `home.php`  inside the `View/cp/`.

so in your code this should be

```
$this->load->view('home','');
```

change to this

```
$this->load->view('cp/home',''); # or cp/home.blade
```

Comment: @S.M_Emamian im here to share my knowledge. Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load 'home', but you view file is called 'home.blade' and is in folder 'cp', so you need to load 'cp/home.blade'.

```
$this->load->view('cp/home.blade')
```